# Display 2 decimal places, and use commas to separate thousands, in Jupyter/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm working with pandas 0.18 in Jupyter.

I'd like to configure Jupyter/pandas to display 2 decimal places throughout, and to use comma separators in thousands.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Configure the following [option](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options) in any cell:

```
pandas.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
```

You can also format the output for any float throughout the notebook with this [magic command](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-precision):

```
%precision %.2f
```

Comment: I don't know how to add a thousands separator for any float in the notebook, only for pandas.

Comment: Is there a way to make this option permanent when I open a notebook? Or do I have to run the command for each notebook?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the display.precision option with e.g.:

```
pd.set_option('precision', 7)
```

when you are done, reset it back using

```
pd.reset_option('precision')
```

as documented in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

Comment: `pd.set_option('display.precision', 2)` is the right syntax for having 2 decimal places, and `pd.reset_option('display.precision')` for reset the option

Comment: `pandas.set_option('precision', 0)` returns `OptionError: 'Pattern matched multiple keys'` while `pd.set_option('display.precision', 2)` works.